# Set up file and registry redirection for a given (new) process in Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization

I want to set up path redirection in both files and registry keys in the same manner UAC virtualization works for another process at launch time (either programmatically or using some existing interface).

For example, I want to run *C:\my_path\app.exe* and when it opens any file on disk (*C:\other_path\file.txt*) for writing, the actual open file should be *C:\temp_for_my_app\C\other_path\file.txt*.

I've seen some programs are able to set up such redirection (i.e. Sandboxie), but I'm unsure which mechanism they are using (not even sure if it is the same UAC virtualization uses).

Any insight into the way UAC virtualization implements it might be useful (your comment on this will be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

Try `cmregistercallback()` or API HOOKING to hook `zwopenkey()` and `zwcreatekey()`